# Sorting Facebook data using python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7

I am retrieving data from Facebook, the retrieved data gives me information about my Facebook friends likes.

I have written this:

```
import requests # pip install requests
import json
ACCESS_TOKEN='' #my Facebook access token here

base_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me'

# Get 10 likes for 10 friends
fields = 'id,name,friends.limit(10).fields(likes.limit(10))'

url = '%s?fields=%s&access_token=%s' %(base_url, fields, ACCESS_TOKEN,)

# This API is HTTP-based and could be requested in the browser,
# with a command line utlity like curl, or using just about
# any programming language by making a request to the URL.
# Click the hyperlink that appears in your notebook output
# when you execute this code cell to see for yourself...

print url

# Interpret the response as JSON and convert back
# to Python data structures

content = requests.get(url).json()

# Pretty-print the JSON and display it

print json.dumps(content, indent=1)

###############################More Options########################################
# Get all likes for 10 friends
fields = 'id,name,friends.limit(10).fields(likes)'
# Get all likes for 10 more friends
fields = 'id,name,friends.offset(10).limit(10).fields(likes)'
# Get 10 likes for all friends
fields = 'id,name,friends.fields(likes.limit(10))'
```

I have used `execfile('Filename.py')` command in order to run this code on python interactive shell.
Now what I want to do is to store the  retrieved data in a text file called "likes.txt".
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Who would you like to store the data? You can make this code store the data on its own by `open`ing a file and dumping whatever you want there, or you can use use `Popen` to run the process and receive the `stdout` data in your main process. Which solution are you aiming for?

Comment: Yea I want to open a file and sort data on it how can I do this?